# es posible usar un loop con esta linea de codigo que usa index?

Tags: python, while, bucles

esta es la linea que no se si se pueda poner en un loop:

```
segunda_m = segunda_m[-1] + segunda_m[-2] + segunda_m[-3] + segunda_m[-4]
#abajo esta todo el codigo completo. es simplemente sumar index.
#El primero es -1 el segundo es -2 y asi consecutivamente.
```

estoy viendo como hacer un programa que reconozca palindromes. (ejemplo:abba,rallar,etc.)

este es mi codigo:

```
palabra = "abcddcba" #8 letras

primera_m = palabra[ :4] # primera mitad de la palabra = 'abcd'
segunda_m = palabra [4: ] # segunda mitad de la palabra = 'dcba'


segunda_m = segunda_m[-1] + segunda_m[-2] + segunda_m[-3] + segunda_m[-4] # aqui invierto el orden de segunda_m para que sea igual a primera_m 

#8 letras repite (segunda_m[-1] + segunda_m[-2] + segunda_m[-3] + segunda_m[-4]) 



print(primera_m) #primera_m es igual a segunda_m = 'abcd'
print(segunda_m) # ='abcd'
```

Comment: No respondo a tu pregunta, pues no la entiendo bien, pero una forma rápida de verificar palíndromes es comparar la cadena con el resultado de invertir la cadena, que python te da con `cadena[::-1]`. Es decir, es palíndromo si `cadena == cadena[::-1]`. Si el palíndromo puede contener espacios, como en: "no traces en ese carton" debes eliminar los espacios antes de hacer el test.

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo confusa, pero si es posible utilizar ciclos en las lineas que estás utilizando, no veo el porque no debería, a menos que vayas a modificar segunda_m mientras se itera si afectaría.